# regex replace not replacing (google apps script)

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, google-apps-script, google-apps

I am writing a google apps script that pulls the content from a CSV file in a gmail attachment. I need to split the csv data into several an array (with each row being it's own array). I've got all that down.

My problem is this: One of the values in the CSV is a "City, St" format. So when I split the array using  string.split(',') I end up with an extra "column."  My idea to fix this was to back up and kill that comma in the initial string. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
    var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      var attachmentData = attachments[k].getDataAsString();
      var regex = new RegExp('\,\s(?:[A-Z]{2}\")', 'gi');
      attachmentData.replace(regex,' ');
...
```

So what I'm trying to do is just find a comma, followed by a space, followed by exactly two letters, then a quotation mark. I want to just replace the comma with a space.  I've also tried

```
      var regex = new RegExp('(\,\s)([A-Z]{2}\")', 'gi');
      attachmentData.replace(regex,$2);
```

with no luck. Here's a random sample of the (very long) data string I'm running this on:

> Voice,Incoming,(###) ###-####,(###) ###-####,,,,"Dallas, TX",12/12/2014,06:26 PM,Phone Call,Voicemail,00:00:27,$0.000,-,, 
>    ,Incoming,(###) ###-####,,###,,,"Dallas, TX",12/12/2014,06:26 PM,Phone Call,Voicemail,00:00

Can anyone see what I'm not seeing as to why this isn't working? (Or have any ideas of a better way to do this?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches
>   of a pattern         replaced by a replacement.

The `str.replace` does not change the string, where as returns a new string with the replace. Hence you may want to write something like

```
var regex = new RegExp('(,\\s)([A-Z]{2}")', 'gi');
var replacedData = attachmentData.replace(regex,'$2');
```

**Note**

You can drop the first capture group as

```
var regex = new RegExp(',\\s([A-Z]{2}")', 'gi');
var replacedData = attachmentData.replace(regex,'$1');
```

Comment: ::facepalm:: Of course it doesn't replace the string. I've been working in arrays too much in this script, I guess. Thanks for that. I'd upvote if I had the rep. 
EDIT: "I'm getting ReferenceError:"$2" is not defined." when I plug this into the script.

Comment: @mulliweht you should wrap `$2` in quotes sorry for the typo :(

Comment: @mulliweht You are welcome :) You can even drop the first caputure group. See the Note in answer. Hope ti helps you

Comment: See also the need to double escape : not `\s` but `\\s`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a regex with this condition and then print back the block with `$1` together with the space:

```
s = s.replace(/,( [A-Z]{2}")/, ' $1');
               ^^         ^    ^^^
           comma ^^^^^^^^^     print back replacing comma with space
                   |
                   catch the group of space + two letters + "
```

See it live:

```js
var s = 'Voice,Incoming,(###) ###-####,(###) ###-####,,,,"Dallas, TX",12/12/2014,06:26 PM,Phone Call,Voicemail,00:00:27,$0.000,-,, ,Incoming,(###) ###-####,,###,,,"Dallas, TX",12/12/2014,06:26 PM,Phone Call,Voicemail,00:00';
s = s.replace(/,( [A-Z]{2})/, ' $1');
document.write(s)
```

Comment: I like that idea of just capturing the 2nd half. Thanks.